# C++ Read CSV file until end of line, not finding last cell

Tags: c++, csv, parsing, getline

I'm reading in a CSV file that has columns of different lengths that looks something like this:

```
1,2,3,4\n
5,,7,\n
9,,11,\n
```

And my problem is that I want it to read the following into a vector:

```
1 2 3 4
5 nan 7 nan
9 nan 11 nan
```

So I'm using the following:

```
int i = 0;
while(getline(data,line))               // Read each line
{
std::stringstream lineStream(line);     
while(getline(lineStream,cell,','))     // Read each cell in the line
{
    if(cell.empty())                    // If ,, use NaN
    {
        strains.push_back(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
    }
    else
    {
        strains.push_back(std::stod(cell));
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that it's skipping the empty cells that end the lines, so it's outputting:

```
1 2 3 4
5 nan 7 9
nan 11
```

Do y'all have any idea how I could count that last column even if it's empty? I'm thinking about having an "if row length < 4, add empty cell" kind of thing. Thank you

**EDIT** I fixed it with that last thing, I put a counter to count how many cells, and then at the end of the inner loop I added:

```
if(j<cols) // If counted less than 12 columns,
{
    strains.push_back(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
}
```

If you have any suggestions or corrections though I'm open to it, thanks.

Comment: No remaining question here, then?

Comment: Unless there's a better way of going about it, no. Thank you.

Comment: Consider replacing `if(j<cols)` with `while(j<cols)` to catch lines that end 2 or more elements too soon.

Comment: This can also occur where the file did not contain a `POSIX EOF` (e.g. a `'\n'` following the final line). You cannot rely on this as a significant minority of editors still do not enforce a POSIX EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another method to parse input from a stringstream. I made a sample program illustrating another way to use `getline`. I would have made a complete function, but you don't have any in your original question, so I added plenty of comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  // Test cases.
  std::istringstream lineStream("1,2,3,4\n");
  //std::istringstream lineStream("5,,7,\n");
  //std::istringstream lineStream("9,,11,\n");

  // Vector of 10-char arrays
  std::vector<std::array<char, 10>> output;
  // "NaN" array, instead of recreating it each iteration.
  std::array<char, 10> NaN = { 'N', 'a', 'N'};

  // Split lineStream on 10 characters, or comma, in cell variable.
  // NOTE : Here, I assume you have maximum 10 characters field, but adjust
  // this based on your specific case. Also, this will capture the "\n", so
  // we'll need to handle that.
  for (std::array<char, 10> cell; lineStream.getline(&cell[0], 10, ','); )
  {
      // Replace the \n character with an end of string.
      // NOTE : this is basic character filtering, and doesn't handle
      // tabulations, or windows-style endline, so it should probably be
      // more robust.
      std::replace(cell.begin(), cell.end(), '\n', '\0');

      // Check if cell is empty, and assign it "NaN"      
      if((cell[0] == '\0') || (cell.empty()))
        cell = NaN;
      // Push the cell back to the output vector.
      output.push_back(cell);
  }

  // Display the output vector
  for (auto& a : output)
  {
    std::cout << &a[0] << " ";
  }
```